# How to Capture Alias for DataBind ?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

I need capture Alias of query SQL Server for my DataBind

My Query

`string sqlConsulta = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), data_recebimento, 103) AS d1`

I need get the alias 'd1'.It is possible ? How to make this ?

I trying make with Eval('d1'), but the alias is not captured. Only columns is captured ...

thanks

Comment: That should work. Try enclosing the d1 in brackets: [d1] in your select statement. I've never had an issue with it.

Comment: You may also want to try pulling the data as is and converting it outside of SQL

Comment: Excellent! Can you share the solution with us?